# Codeigniter secure sessions

Tags: security, codeigniter, session

I have  question about how the secure session works. When enabled, does it secure the views too?

I want to create a simple secure session where it would detect an admin/user is logging and display the info only for that user.

I could use some clarification please, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure session"?

Answer (score 2):

The safest way you can go with CI sessions is to set a session encryption key (I believe recent versions even force you to do it) and use the database for storing sessions. But don't forget: nothing is 100% secure, and you should do everything you can to reduce the risks.

Comment: Ya, I ahve that enabled already with a key implemented. I was just wondering if Codeigniter is doing a secure session, does that also secure th e HTML pages in the View folder.

Comment: What do you mean? You can access the views only via controllers.